# Mysql : can't set lower_case_table_names variable

Tags: mysql

I'm installing new software on a new Ubuntu 16.0.4 machine and installed MySQL with apt-get. The version I get is 5.7.22 but can't get it to accept
my settings of the configuration variable lower_case_table_names.

I'm adding lines like:

```
[mysql]
lower_case_table_names = 1
```

When I edit any of the *.cnf files in /etc/mysql to have this setting or if I add it to ~/.my.cnf I get

```
mysql: [ERROR] unknown variable 'lower_case_table_names=1'
```

if I try to start mysql.   Similarly I can't use it on the mysql command line like the doc says I can.

```
/usr/bin/mysql --lower_case_table_names=1 -u root -p
```

However:

If I go into the SQL command interpreter  and type

```
mysql> select @@lower_case_table_names;
```

I get back a result showing the variable is set to 0.  However it cannot be changed with a SET statement...

So whats the deal with why I can't set this variable ?

~/.my.cnf file:

```
[mysqld]
lower_case_table_names = 1
[mysql]
lower_case_table_names = 1
```

Why is mysql not liking this variable name when clearly it still has a setting for it?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that this variable does not apply to mysql.  It only applies
to mysqld.  Stop mysqld, change the my.cnf to have a setting for [mysqld], and then start mysqld.     This will set the lower_case_table_names value for the mysql server.

If you run /usr/bin/mysql (a command line mysql shell) it will not want a setting for this var in the config file.  The shell will behave as the mysql server behaves.